# Clone not copying input value in Chrome, but working in Mozilla

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, input, clone

This is code of HTML.
This code is working in Mozilla but not working in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <ul id="myList1">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="myList2">
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>
        <input id="files" name="files" type="file" />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>Click the button to copy an item from one list to another.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p>Try changing the <em>deep</em> parameter to false, and only an  empty LI element will be cloned.</p>
    <script>
      function myFunction() 
      {
        var itm = document.getElementById("myList2").lastChild;
        var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(cln);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can You Please Precise your Question a bit more clear

Comment: can you please not post comments as answers?

Answer (score 0):

`lastChild` includes all node children, including text-nodes. So what you got was not an element but a text-node with the newline and space between `</li>` and `</ul>`.

So what you want is the last child Element, not the last child Node.

Which you can do with

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var itm = document.getElementById("myList2").lastElementChild;
  var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(cln);
}
```